# Installing OpenCV on Raspberry Pi: can't find packages

Tags: raspbian, python, linux, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV 2.4.7 on Raspberry Pi (Model B, OS: Raspbian).

The guides I'm referring to are:
1. [RASPBERRY PI + SIMPLECV + OPENCV + RASPICAM CSI CAMERA](http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/59305587476/raspberry-pi-simplecv-opencv-raspicam-csi-camera)
2. [Raspberry Pi + OpenCV](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/)
3. ... Don't have enough rep to link them all.

The problem is that I can't install all the required packages in order to be able to install OpenCV since I get the error:`E: Unable to locate package package_name`.

Here the list of packages I can't install (output of raspbian terminal):
`Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package libucil2

E: Unable to locate package libucil2-dev

E: Unable to locate package libpngwriter0-dev

E: Unable to locate package libpngwriter0c2

E: Unable to locate package libavcodec52

E: Unable to locate package libavformat52

E: Unable to locate package libswscale0`

Can anybody help me to get throughout this?

Additional information:
I'm connecting to Raspberry Pi through SSH (using PUTTY on Windows 7).
Raspberry Pi is correctly connected to internet through ethernet (I tested the connection using the midori web browser on raspbian).
I've tried several solutions found on the net but none solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV 2.4.* does not work on the Raspberry Pi.  The latest stable version that works on the Raspberry Pi is OpenCV 2.3.1, which is what your second website links to.  The reason for this is the lack of an official [V4L driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux).

The reason you can't find those packages is because they are out of date.  Substitute
`libavcodec53` and `libavformat53` for `libavcodec52` and `libavformat52` and it should work.
Newer versions of `libpngwriter0-dev` and `libpngwriter0c2` are not available, but does not seem to affect the build.

Other than that, following your second links tutorial (where you compile it yourself) worked just fine for me.

Comment: thank Yes I successfully installed OpenCV 2.3.1. I thought I could just do the same with 2.4.6. Anyway, thank you for your answer and clarifications!